# How to force user logout on sub-domain modification?

Tags: asp.net, security, forms-authentication

**DNS has a wildcard for *.website.com to point to website.com.**

`Client A` is given a url like: http://clientA.website.com/ and hits the same login page as `client B`.  `Client A` logs in and then changes the subdomain to `client B's`. How do I force the user back to the login page automatically when the user changes the subdomain?

Will this do the trick?

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms slidingExpiration="true" loginUrl="Views\Login.aspx" 
        defaultUrl="Views\Login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="300" 
        cookieless="UseCookies" enableCrossAppRedirects="false" 
        domain="*.website.com" <!--Will this property and value do what I want?-->
        name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH"/>
    </authentication>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When they log in you could do this:

```
Session["validhost"] = Request.Url.Host;
```

and then in Global.asax.cs you could have this:

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (Session["validhost"] != null && Request.Url.Host != Session["validhost"]){
    Session.Abandon();
    //some sort of redirect
  }
}
```

You could definitely make some changes to this based on how you have things stored on your site, but this basic pattern will work.

Comment: Thanks for the post.  This is one possible solution.  I was kind of hoping that forms authentication would some how handle this for me automatically.